# Custom fonts .jar maven dependency for Jasperreports

Tags: java, maven, fonts, jasper-reports

I've created fonts.jar with fonts that I'm needed for jasperreports.

Added it to the resources folder and dependencies at pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fonts</groupId>
        <artifactId>fonts</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/fonts.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Through local runs with IDEA it works, and when I'm trying to remove dependency from pom.xml it stops. That means that adding to classpath works through Maven, right?.

But on the remote node deployed through TeamCity it's throwing JRFontNotFoundException and can't find the font needed.

Is there a solution to add jasperreports custom fonts jar to the Java application?

Comment: Don't use `<scope>system</scope>`, install the JAR to your local repository, or use a repo manager.

Comment: @Tunaki, I've even added it to nexus, but still. It works with IDEA and JRFontNotFoundException on the remote node :(